Замена не-ссылок
Есть html - текст, в нем есть теги. Нужно найти и заменить определенное слово, но без замен внутри кавычек. То есть слово -> замена, но "слово" "\"слово" -> "слово" "\"слово"

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://regex101.com/r/25vhYi/1 - попробуйте составить выражение самостоятельно, там есть набросок (?<=\s|^)[^\/]+(?=\s|$)
